# Switch between Dragon NaturallySpeaking and Windows Speech Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition

I did a generalized search on Stack exchange, searching for anything related to speech recognition to decide which of the specific sites this question would best fit.  I finally settled on this one due to the fact that every search came up with results from this site.  So my question is how can I easily switch between Dragon NaturallySpeaking and Windows Speech Recognition.  I currently have installed Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13, Windows Speech Recognition, and Windows Speech Recognition Macros.  With WSR I can simply use the macros to script up a macro that pushes the keys necessary to turn on Dragon and turn off Windows Speech Recognition.  However, Dragon 13 is currently only available in home and premium editions, meaning there are no script macros available.  I have looked at using AutoHotKey, AutoIT, and even basic batch files.  No solutions have thus far presented themselves to me, of course I am not a very experienced programmer yet, so I don't exactly know if I am searching correctly.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi, I kindly suggest you to read the guidelines on how to post a question. Perhaps SO is not the right place for this question, since here we talk about coding, and there is basically no coding involve in your post.

Comment: Actually there is, for the simple fact that it requires programming in order to do what I need.  For example, that batch scripts are still programming, as any programming done via vocola is still programming.

Comment: I still invite you to read the SO guidelines on how to post e question. You are not asking a specific question, but your have asked an open question asking for generic suggestions, which is against the SO guidelines

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's asking for open suggestions to me, I am asking for a specific method of how to do so, the question is within the rules.  I asked a specific question of how I can switch between Dragon and Windows speech recognition via programming code.  I think you are simply misunderstood in the question.